# KL divergence estimates over binary classification data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, entropy, kullback-leibler

I have a dataset $D = (x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n$ where $x_i\in \Bbb R^d$ and $y_i\in\{0, 1\}$. Suppose that $y\sim\mathrm{Bernoulli}(p(x))$ for some probability function $p:\Bbb R^d \to [0,1]$ and I would like to learn this function the best way I can. Say, I have some estimate $q$ of $p$. How can I approximate the KL divergence $\mathrm{KL}(q(x), p(x))$ at a given validation sample point $x\in \Bbb R^d$?

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.08501), I can get
$$
\mathrm{KL}(q(x), p(x)) = \mathrm{CE}(q(x), p(x)) - \mathrm H(p(x))
$$
which also would represent the epistemic uncertainty of estimate $q$ at a point $x$. Since I don't know the two terms in the RHS precisely either, I can approximate them as follows (see my e.g.  [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547088/binary-classification-but-learning-the-true-probability))
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{CE}(q(x), p(x)) &\approx -[y = 1]\cdot \log q(x) - [y=0]\cdot \log(1 - q(x))
\\
\mathrm H(p(x))&\approx = -q(x)\cdot \log q(x) - (1 - q(x))\cdot \log(1 - q(x))
\end{align}
$$
where in the second approximation I've assumed $\mathrm H(p(x)) \approx \mathrm H(q(x))$.

Unfortunately, if I take the difference between the two I get
$$
\mathrm{KL}(q(x), p(x)) \approx ([y=1] - q(x))\cdot\log\frac{1-q(x)}{q(x)}
$$
which seems to be a bad estimate to me as RHS can surely go negative, whereas the LHS is a non-negative distance. How should I get a correct estimate of $\mathrm{KL}(q(x), p(x))$?

Comment: Do you really need to estimate the KL divergence, or do you just want to minimize it?

Comment: I need its estimate indeed, not only the $q$ that minimizes it

Comment: If you don't know $p$, then I don't think the KL divergence (KLD) *can* be computed, since the KL divergence takes in a reference $p$ and an estimate $q$ as inputs. You write "and I would like to learn this function the best way I can." If your goal is to estimate $p$, then you can either do this by guessing an initial $p$, computing the gradient of the KLD with respect to $p$, and then using gradient descent or some other method. You can also minimize the cross entropy instead, since the entropy $H(x)$ is non-negative.

Comment: @mhdadk I did not write "compute", I wrote "estimate" - like everything we hope for in ML.